# split the text and make a list of list

Tags: python, list, split

I have text file and I want to split the files and make it list where it is starting from @Given, @When and @And  and put in a list, below files look like this

```
@Given
 User Username{
 User Userpassowrd 
 User ID 
 }
@When
User Username{
User Userpassowrd 
User ID 
}
@And
User Username{
User Userpassowrd 
User ID 
}
```

and i want to out put like this ,

Final_List=

```
      [@Given
      User Username{
      User Userpassowrd 
      User ID 
         }],
       [@When
        User Username{
        User Userpassowrd 
        User ID 
        }],
        [@And
         User Username{
         User Userpassowrd 
         User ID 
          }]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: # with open(r'textfile.txt', 'r') as f:
#     paragraphs2 = f.read().split(@given  or @when, or @And) but that did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use *for loop* to iterate over lines of `txtFile` by *split('\n')* with *break line* and `startswith` to check if it start with '@' ot with *closing curly brace* '}' store lines in `list` and finally join them back with new line *'\n'* and show them with print!

```py
txtFile = """
@Given
 User Username{
 User Userpassowrd 
 User ID 
 }
@When
User Username{
User Userpassowrd 
User ID 
}
@And
User Username{
User Userpassowrd 
User ID 
}
"""
output = []
for line in txtFile.split('\n'):
    if(line.startswith("@")):
        output.append('['+line)
    elif(line.strip().startswith("}")):
        output.append(line+"],")
    else:
        output.append(line)
print('\n'.join(output)[0:-2])
```

*Result:*

```
[@Given
 User Username{
 User Userpassowrd
 User ID
 }],
[@When
User Username{
User Userpassowrd
User ID
}],
[@And
User Username{
User Userpassowrd
User ID
}]
```

Comment: Thanks !! but i want  @Given to } in index 0  , When to } in index 1 and And  to } in index 2 of Output list .

Comment: Welcome, I've fixed it by adding ',' near the end of bracket and removing the last ',' by slicing two chars ',\n'

Comment: Sorry !! but same issue i am facing ,  ',' is adding after end bracket but no result , I want from   , [@Given
 User Username{
 User Userpassowrd
 User ID
 }]     this should be in index 0 ,  [@When
User Username{
User Userpassowrd
User ID
}], This should be in index 1 , soo.....ON